# How do I configure Intellij to allow node import assertions?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I have the following code...

[image]

It compiles and functions just fine with the `--experimental-json-modules` flag but it still shows the following error on the red tilda...

[image]

I am already configured to use ECMAScript6+ so what else do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import assertions proposal is supported since version 2021.3, see [WEB-52552](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52552); please consider upgrading IDEA to the most recent version

Comment: Afaik I am on the newest version

Comment: works fine for me there; check your Help> About